# What is the difference between e.target.parentNode and e.path[1]

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering what the difference between the `e.target.parentNode` and `e.path[1]` is? And if there is, what is better & why?

Here is how the sturcture looks like:

[image]

Here ist the console log:

```
console.log("button clicked!!!",e.target.parentNode, e.path[1], e.path[2])
```

[image]

Here is the click `console.log(e)`

[image]

**NB: click event is on the button element**

Thank you

Comment: Please post markup as *markup*, not a picture.

Comment: Well I believe `path` is not available in every current browser.

Comment: What is `e`? Please show us your code.

Comment: @Bergi  e is the target in my case it is the button element child of li

Comment: @Bansoaistheanswer: Er, I don't think it is. I think it's an `Event` instance received in response to a click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimentally, on the one browser I've found that supports it, `e.path[1]` and `e.target.parentNode` refer to the same element. E.g., there's no difference.

But note that `Event#path` is not well-supported (whereas `Event#target` and `Node#parentNode` are), and as far as I can tell, it's not (yet?) standardized: It doesn't appear in the [DOM4 `Event` interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-event), for instance. It's also not in the [WHAT-WG `Event` interface](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-event), but that spec does mention a *method*, [`composedPath`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-composedpath), that appears to return the same sort of information.

Chrome 51 seems to support `Event#path`; Firefox 47 does not. Neither supports `composedPath`.

You can see if your current browser supports it here:

```js
document.getElementById("outer").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var hasPath = !!e.path;
  var hasComposePath = !!e.composedPath;
  console.log("Has `path`? " + (hasPath ? "Yes" : "No"));
  console.log("Has `composedPath()`? " + (hasComposePath ? "Yes" : "No"));
  if (hasPath) {
    console.log("e.path[1] === e.target.parentNode? " + (e.path[1] === e.target.parentNode));
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    Click me
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be documented *at all* anywhere. I could not find any mention in the [current DOM spec draft](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) either. The only mention is in the [polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events)

Comment: @Bergi: It's supported by Chrome 51. I haven't found a spec for it yet, it may well not be in one (yet?).

Comment: The only things I found are [`composedPath()`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-composedpath) and [`deepPath()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#widl-Event-deepPath-sequence-EventTarget) methods. Looks very experimental.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I found `composedPath` too.